# How to get the base path of system-wide .NET Core runtime environment?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

When I run `dotnet --info`, among other information I receive also:

```
Runtime Environment:
 ...
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0
```

Is there any way to get this value programatically in C# application running under .NETCoreApp framework? I'm particularly interested in its `Sdks` subdirectory, as I need to provide it to a hosted instance of MSBuild when processing some .NET Core projects. Therefore, properties such as `AppContext.BaseDirectory` are no use to me, because they point to the path of the current application.

I'll probably end up launching `dotnet --info` and parsing its results, but I wonder whether a more elegant way exists. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Originaly there was mistakenly `dotnet --version` instead of `dotnet --info`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the "dotnet --info" command from your application and parse the output.

Quick and dirty:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var basePath = GetDotNetCoreBasePath();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static String GetDotNetCoreBasePath()
    {
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = "dotnet",
                Arguments = "--info"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        if (process.HasExited)
        {
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) == false)
            {
                var reg = new Regex("Base Path:(.+)");
                var matches = reg.Match(output);
                if (matches.Groups.Count >= 2)
                    return matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("DotNet Core Base Path not found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions/

`ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` will give you what you're looking for. I found this by looking at the `dotnet` source code...

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/f62ca5e235e253c033c628a39852d5923d53688a/src/dotnet/Program.cs#L251

Comment: I thought that too, but unfortunately it returns the directory where the compiled application's assembly is located, such as `...\myapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0`. It works for `dotnet --info` only because the CLI tools themselves are located in the desired directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0`).